# Как установить 2 разные версии gulp на 1 ПК

Tags: windows, gulp, gulp-sass

у меня ранее стояла версия gulp 2.* и она работала отлично с моими проектами и сборкой, но появился новый клиент у которого проект на версии 4 alpha. Мне сказали что можно установить как то 2 версии, но я не могу найти инфу в инете как это сделать?
Для того чтобы мне запустить новый проект мне пришлось установить новую версию npm и обновить gulp до последней версии.

Сейчас если в обеих проектах прописываю gulp -v то выдает такое:

```
CLI version 1.2.2
Local version 4.0.0-alpha.2
```

И в предыдущем проекте :

```
CLI version 1.2.2
Local version 3.9.1
```

При этом когда пытаюсь установить и запустить gulp на старом проекте мне выдает ошибку:

```
module.js:538
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object. (E:\uniphantcode\test\gulpfile.js:4:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
```

Comment: Так и установите нужную версию не глобально  с постфиксом `-g`, а в проект локально с постфиксом `-D`